# why this loop doesn't run correctly if i don't check the existence of var td?

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, input

I have this function  from w3schools that makes the search box accepts an input and then search the table for data that match the input value.
i get the whole code....except the part when it insert the if and else statement inside a parent if statement "  if( td) " and the code won't even run without the if statement, why that happens ? why do i need to set a condition that is already true and not going to change since there will always td!

```
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Beware code from w3schools, it's often awful (as it is above).

Answer (score 0):

> except the part when it insert the `if` and `else` statement inside a parent `if` statement " `if( td)` " and the code won't even run without the if statement, why that happens ?

If you open the developer tools of your browser, when you remove that `if` statement, if the code doesn't run it's because your HTML has rows that don't have any cells in them, like this:

```
<tr></tr>
```

The `if` statement is guarding against that.

> why do i need to set a condition that is already true and not going to change since there will always `td`!

Well, if the code is failing when you remove that `if` statement, clearly there *aren't* always `td`s inside all `tr`s.

---

Side note: The code can be much more concise and targeted than that, even if we limit ourselves to things that were only present in ES5 and don't use any ES2015+ features:

```
function myFunction() {
    var filter = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
    Array.protoype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr > td:first-child"),
        function(td) {
            td.parentNode.style.display =
                td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == -1 ? "none" : "";
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "`if (td)`" test is important because you could have an empty row, with no `td`s, so `td` from `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` should be undefined and the code execution should error out.
You can check javascript errors using your browser's developer console (usually toggled with `<f12>` key...